# Return unique document per Mongo IN query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm querying a `Collection` that has 350k+ `Documents`. I'm querying a `field` using the `IN` clause where the `IN` is an array of 27k+ fields.

This actually seems to return rather fast in `Mongoose`. However, some of the matches of each item in the `IN` can have multiple `Documents` associated with them. I'd like to only have 1 Document returned per each match (sorted by another field). Is this possible?

**Example**
Let's say I have a `Collection` of Fruit.

```
[
 {type:'apple', price:10},{type:'apple', price:5},{type:'apple', price:3},
 {type:'orange', price:2},
 {type:'pear', price:12}, {type:'pear', price:2}
]
```

So, currently I have

```
const types = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'];

//Will return full example above
//Returns 12k Docs in real app but bc multiple Docs are returned per item in IN

Fruit.find({type: { $in: types }}, (err, results) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(results);
});
```

I'd like to just have

```
 [
         {type:'apple', price:10}
         {type:'orange', price:2},
         {type:'pear', price:12}
    ]
```

How can I adjust my query to do something like this? Thanks!
returned. So instead of all documents matching the type - I just get only 1 with the highest price.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `type` and use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html) to get highest prices:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { type: { $in: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$type",
            price: { $max: "$price" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            type: "$_id",
            _id: 0,
            price: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t43CBRhGoLa)